# Incremental Data Load in Azure Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to do delta load from Azure Devops to Azure Kusto Cluster using ADF. As Kusto doesn't have an option to update or delete specific records, I have followed the below steps to implement incremental data load.

1. Data will be loaded as a full load into main table (Table A) for the first time.
2. I will get the Max modified date from Table A and load only the latest modified data into TableStg in Kusto with the following filter.(>=(maxmodifieddate-1 day)
3. I will create a Temp table (TableTemp) here in Kusto to merge modified/new data (from TableStg) and exisiting data into single table and then replace the main table (Table A) with Temp table using below KQL.

`.set-or-replace  TableTemp with (distributed=true) <| set notruncation;let updated=TableStg|union TableA |summarize maxdate=max(ChangedDate) by WorkItemId;let mergeupdate=(TableStg|union TableTemp)|distinct *|join kind=inner updated on $left.WorkItemId==$right.WorkItemId|whereChangedDate==maxdate;mergeupdate| project-away WorkItemId1, maxdate`

`.drop table TableA ifexists ;`

`.rename tables TableA=TableTemp;`

With large number of records, this query is failing with below memory error.

*"error": {
"code": "LimitsExceeded",
"message": "Request is invalid and cannot be executed.",
"@type": "Kusto.DataNode.Exceptions.KustoQueryRunawayException",
"@message": "HResult: 0x80DA0001, source: (Partial query failure: Low memory condition (E_LOW_MEMORY_CONDITION). (message: 'bad allocation', details: ''))"*

Is there any option to optimize this query and achieve delta load?

Do we have any other way to implement incremental load in Azure Kusto?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of more (simpler) options:

1. You may be able to use [update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy), if you guarantee that each ADF ingestion happens after the previous one completed.
2. You can also use [materialized-views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/materialized-views/materialized-view-overview) to apply the "last updated" logic.